# uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list i know its super common but i cant see where i messed up

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I've been working on this for a while now and just can't find the issue dev tools are telling me it's on line 23

Here is the code

```
1   <script>
2
3   var comp1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
4   var comp2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
5   var you1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
6   var you2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
7   var counter = 1;
8   var youPoints = 0;
9   var mePoints = 0;
10
11
12  while(counter < 6)
13  {
14      alert("Let's shake some dice!");
15      alert("your turn to roll \n\n you shook a " + you1 + " and a " +  you2 + ", so you have " + (you1 + you2));
16
17      alert("my turn to roll \n\n I shook a " + comp1 + " and a " +  comp2 + ", so I have " + (comp1 + comp2));
18
19      var you = you1 + you2;
20      var me = comp1 + comp2;
21      if(you > me)
22      {
23          alert("you win " + you " to " + me);
24          youPoints++
25      }
26
27
28      counter++
29  }
30
31
32  </script>
```

---

i'm using sublime Text so i can see good seperation between things and it all looks good to me but its just now working  hopefully one of you guys can catch the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable without adding a plus after it in the log statment

```
alert("you win " + you + " to " + me);
```

That's why it was expecting a closing Parenthesis after 'you' but saw a string.